# Loop over XML stored in MySQL with Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

Client uploads images and the system pulls the meta info from them and stores it as XML in the database.

Looks like this:

```
 <wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><struct>
<var name='Exif'><struct><var name='Orientation'><string>
Top, left side (Horizontal / normal)</string></var>...
```

I am looping over the images and need to also loop over this string to pull certain vars out (artist, title, description).

I've tried everything i can think of but am getting errors like "cant cast string to type array".

If anyone can suggest a solution, i'm in your debt!

Comment: It appears to be stored as a wddx packet rather than straight XML, have a look at the <cfwddx> tag (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ca6.html) where you should be able to convert the packet into a ColdFusion datatype.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jedihomer, I tried this code but got this error:

<cfquery name="myxml" datasource="dsn">
Select metainfo from dmImage
</cfquery>

     <!--- Deserialize to a variable named wddxResult. ---> 
     Deserializing WDDX packet...<p> 
     <cfwddx action="wddx2cfml" input="#myxml#" output="wddx">


Error:  Can't cast Complex Object Type Query to String

Comment: You'll want to include the column of the DB... so for the input use input="#myxml.metainfo#".  This way it will pass in the string from the database rather than trying to pass the query object into it.

Comment: Why are you storing wddx in your database? A better design would be to parse the data BEFORE storing in database.You can then store the date in relatoinal tables that would be easier to manage/retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

As others in comments have suggested, WDDX is a way to store structured data - a bit like Json is typically used. You'll want to pass the column/string to the wddx tag.

```
<cfwddx action="wddx2cfml" input="#queryname.colmname#" output="imgData">

<cfdump var="#imgData#">
```

That should get you moving along the right path. From there you will have something along the lines of:

```
#imgData.Exif.Orientation#
```

...per your example the above var would contain the string `Top, Left side (Hoirzontal / normal).`

Comment: Thanks everyone.

I tried this code:

<cfquery name="myxml" datasource="scharf">
Select metainfo from dmImage
</cfquery>

<cfwddx action="wddx2cfml" input="#myxml.metainfo#" output="imgData">

<cfdump var="#imgData#">


I got this error:

XML Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.

Comment: This occurs when the WDDX packet is malformed. The most typical way this happens is when it's too long for the field in the DB you are using _OR_ you don't have "enable long text retrieval" checked in the DB advanced properties.